# Find arrays with distinct subarray sums

Tags: combinatorics, fastest-code

Consider an array `A` of length `n`. The array contains only integers in the range `1` to `s`. For example take `s = 6`, `n = 5` and  `A = (2, 5, 6, 3, 1)`. Let us define `g(A)` as the collection of sums of all the non-empty contiguous subarrays of A. In this case `g(A) = [2,5,6,3,1,7,11,9,4,13,14,10,16,15,17]`. The steps to produce `g(A)` are as follows:

The subarrays of A are (2), (5), (6), (3), (1), (2,5), (5,6), (6,3), (3,1), (2,5,6), (5,6,3), (6,3,1),(2,5,6,3), (5,6,3,1), (2,5,6,3,1). Their respective sums are 2,5,6,3,1,7,11,9,4,13,14,10,16,15,17.

In this case all the sums are distinct.

However, if we looked at `g((1,2,3,4))` then the value 3 occurs twice as a sum and so the sums are not all distinct.

**Task**

For each `s` from 1 upwards, your code should output the largest `n` so that there exists an array A  of length n with distinct subarray sums.

Your code should iterate up from `s = 1` giving the answer for each `s` in turn. I will time the entire run, killing it after one minute.

Your score is the highest `s` you get to in that time.

In the case of a tie, the first answer wins.

**Examples**

The answers for `s = 1..12` are `n=1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9`.

**Testing**

I will need to run your code on my ubuntu machine so please include as detailed instructions as possible for how to compile and run your code.

**Leaderboard**

- **s = 19** by Arnauld in **C**

Comment: I don't think the requirement of making the programs output results starting from \$ s=1 \$ is a good idea. Once a particular \$ s \$ value is known, the program could simply output that number instead of doing any calculation. You might instead measure the solution that is able to find the largest \$ s \$ value in under a minute?

Comment: There is a ppcg rule that answers should actually compute the output. If there is a general mathematical rule someone can work out that would be a valid way to do it quickly though. In practice the time will be dominated by the largest s in any case I suspect.

Comment: I am quite certain that there is no such rule. Currently there is nothing stopping anyone from just writing a simple print statement for the first 12 values that you provided and having a score of 12. It is almost certainly true that the largest value will use up most of the time, which is why I think my suggestion makes more sense. It's (of course) fine if you disagree, but I'm pretty sure you are just making your challenge much more annoying to answer for no reason.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman [Hard-coding the output is a standard loophole.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1063/60043)

Comment: @Abigail I see that such function could be argued both ways: hard-coded and not hard-coded. One other example that would lean towards the "not hard-coded" side would be a polynomial function generated by interpolating some precomputed result. I leave the blame on the challenge, since allowing the program to return wrong/unexpected result after a certain point calls for hard-coding the output to some extent.

Comment: @JungHwanMin I think that what Abigail suggests clearly identifies why that doesn't make sense in this case. For fastest-code problems the best strategy will essentially always involve some pre-calculation. Deciding where to cut the line seems like a preposterous problem, so I don't think that loophole makes much sense for fastest-code challenges (or in fact, in general). Thanks though for pointing it out, I can see why users might be confused by it.

Comment: I downvoted this challenge because the nature of this challenge encourages some extent of hard-coding the solutions, and requiring the answer to "actually compute the output" is [a non-observable requirement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10002/60043); there is no clear distinction between what is computed and what is hard-coded.

Comment: @JungHwanMin Oh no! I am confused as the scoring system is basically the same as https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/174407/count-arrays-that-make-unique-sets and https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/165504/delete-some-bits-and-count and https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/157049/calculate-the-hafnian-as-quickly-as-possible and... (and so on). What can I change to make you happy with my question?

Comment: @Anush (Passive aggressiveness aside,) The scoring is not the issue; rather, the problem is that the challenge requires programs that take an integer and return an integer. By nature, this is easy to "hard-code"; see Abigail's example. To decompose this issue further: the first link you posted requires two integer inputs, with a variable-length integer list output. Clearly, effectively hard-coding cases for a pair of inputs is not so easily done. Similar reasoning applies with the second link. The third link takes a variable length input, so hard-coding is out of the question, too.

Comment: @JungHwanMin Thanks. No aggressiveness of any sort intended! Can you suggest how to improve my question please?

Comment: One possibility is to change the output to something not easy to hard-code; for instance, you could require programs to output the list of subarrays or sums thereof. These changes could be too drastic, but since there are no submissions to be invalidated, I think it would be fine to change the specifications.

Comment: @JungHwanMin What's the difference between hard-coding the number `9` and hard-coding an array of length 9? It's good practice to avoid unobservable requirements whenever possible, but it's rather difficult for some kinds of challenges (fastest-code, anything related to quines, etc.).

Comment: @Dennis I presume it would take considerably more effort to indirectly hard-code an array than a number without making it obvious, since the requirement for now is to "compute the output." I understand that hard-coding is still a possibility, though. Perhaps a better change to the challenge would be to output `n` given `s` (for all valid `s`)?

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), s = 19

This is basically a port of my Node.js answer. It goes one step further with the default compiler options and two steps further with `-O2` or `-O3`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void search(uint8_t * arr, int n, uint8_t * sum, int * max, char * str, int depth) {
  int i, j, k, s;
  char tmp[16];

  // do we have a better array?
  if(depth > *max) {
    for(str[0] = '\0', i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
      sprintf(tmp, "%d ", arr[i]);
      strcat(str, tmp);
    }
    *max = depth;
  }

  // try to append i = 1 to n to the current array
  for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    // provided that doing so does not produce a sum that was already encountered
    if(!sum[i]) {
      for(sum[s = i] = 1, j = depth; j && !sum[s += arr[j - 1]]; j--) {
        sum[s] = 1;
      }
      if(!j) {
        // this is valid: set the value in arr[] and do a recursive call
        arr[depth] = i;
        search(arr, n, sum, max, str, depth + 1);
      }
      // whether the recursive call was processed or not, we have to clear the flags
      // that have been set above
      for(sum[s = i] = 0, k = depth - 1; k >= j; k--) {
        sum[s += arr[k]] = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}

int solve(int n, char * str) {
  int     max = 0;              // best length so far
  int     hi = n * (n + 1) / 2; // highest possible sum for n
  uint8_t sum[hi + 1];          // encountered sums
  uint8_t arr[n];               // array

  memset(sum, 0, (hi + 1) * sizeof(uint8_t));
  search(arr, n, sum, &max, str, 0);

  return max;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void main() {
  char str[128];
  int  n, res;

  for(n = 1; n <= 19; n++) {
    res = solve(n, str);
    printf("N = %d --> %d with [ %s]\n", n, res, str);
  }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVRtbhoxEP3PKSZUSZawNJBKVdoN9AbtAciqMruGNVm8yDbQtOLqpW/GfEbpCmF7PJ9v3rjozYpit/tgbFGvSk1PPpSm@ViNWuciZ@zsraw0NrCstW5MSV4rV1TJCsLHn4HuSDmXEk5kUzpJ/WoRpXe0UL9SKirlWBz2yqVehqpDf1okR5PSPKWXlHwGiSiHxXI8@JxnLQju76lsaKOpUmtNiiY6BO04tHr9xi6miTikEd0hXPRLNG1cgojjfk5Dun3u3yI2dv0My1NMAdtu96BP5JdAIEwTBE@pfV1SO@UoY5N3soNKcIUKiVQCtb18K/8cHAGi5xZLY/LBvVJoSC2X2paSw4DPlv9CpalYOacBgxTUiomLlmQ6JHuRJhwuXbM2pS5hrQBmg7aRb7DRnmwT@L5cFQwVGhGVNsqTqp1W5StpWzQrCwh1KR6B3xUUucwjFAIeZB55GAZwgB4di8P25oauokJ3KCDNqUeDPMddr3fyQyRK4uGA4Xa/ctz5uSpjVRlP@K1Vbcqv4FsQiHBcaXBFIuWkgCMoochpgOcNaFGouj46Yi3JlOOa7JRLpK@QFoQVmgpBpZ@RRF0adN5misQ2lUYiTrK5jCrYAvJCe4@eNI57kB75iiYXtVbRclqrmW@dVYvWiNZEayvVqkmz1v9rQh9TcmgCw53hOBrSHOs7oB8685KL7WVRWyEoKMoD6Jt6rZP9GJ@G9TSh/EV2Y3wuPlQx0T5Qre0MSYGGU@XOrCpmsoW/xAq0dE8PGVtVZlax4bLx3kxqLVydMnqwPjwlXAc8wDDPLmKecZiV/JkNl2zzN2myTZwvaC70AlAn0n5AmsQIHS7a/NbN9PC@dYQI75Hm5sSafkceKafDylkGKWttd/JYLpSxScRQMOXHaPDwmGcHeODNaS/m3GobZ97yzA@@YHMaeqjhMrbJSuA9R/cvVvs7rvFg9XojXjYGrRjTtc@fbTvdxzmZoe@7v4Vwcdf78ekf)

Comment: Thanks again! I wonder what speedups will be possible.

Comment: @Anush Just compiling with `-O3` allows to reach \$N=19\$ on TIO.

Comment: Could you add the main function to your answer so people can just copy and paste?

Comment: @Anush Sure. Done.

Answer (score 1):

## [Node.js](https://nodejs.org), s = 17

Just a simple recursive search to get the ball rolling. Returns both the length and a valid array.

```javascript
solve = n => {
  var max = 0,  // best length so far
      best,     // best array so far
      sum = {}; // encountered sums

  (search = a => {
    var i, j, k, s;

    // do we have a better array?
    if(a.length > max) {
      max = a.length;
      best = [...a];
    }

    // try to prepend i = 1 to n to the current array
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      // provided that doing so does not produce a sum that was already encountered
      if((sum[j = 0, s = i] ^= 1) && a.every(n => sum[j++, s += n] ^= 1)) {
        search([i, ...a]);
      }
      // reset the flags that have been toggled above
      for(sum[s = i] ^= 1, k = 0; k < j; k++) {
        sum[s += a[k]] ^= 1;
      }
    }
  })([]);

  return [ max, best ];
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVPNcqJAEL77FH1KsEATT3sgMW@wL0C5VS20gCEz1syIa6V4dvfrAVbjgRm6v5n@fvDIPfvStaewMraS283brhd6J0PvW/peEPXs6Iv/ovSaEb280F58oE5MHRrylg7sgNKfNrK4m1HsHF9/gvz5C1d9D7mCxJT2bII4qbThFwAlXtiVDUA8UxhJtBkdM/rMyOeLxTSlsnQRahiUGSMDrhqHfkREe0h4PVHdqorldB9NkuZu/iAB5WK9XvNuLA7/hwV3pWDp5OQkpqIWwI0WjD5CI1SenRMzyY6nDtYlEZcD/gZXsabpnQVuPTnbtxUMCA0HCGpNrY5VVjwZG7RfnUvVp9ZF0IU9ceeEq@ujhdOdEJ0AWhzHyDyWdkd/QGJJT0@QLL24axIDjrg0VVQKdhPszg95xTSSAu5HU5azVcNdghMvITpw6Lj2I8kYyl5E3anrDgJ5b3uZTqkxOvyBHbJVxjmWNzpieTQqfjhFZMnF52488ZOKPodlUihFbJ2EszNUaNLZGCwSHW76KZlMOQOmNMyYj9F8Nr@wmecCglb8QyQm6i6twausO1snz7/RfKYUB1Osq9U2vuFQ8bqLpUuLz26ubZTWcPsH)

Comment: Thank you for the first answer!